# Eclipse Error Exporting Web Project as WAR

Tags: eclipse, export, war

I have the following error when I export my war file

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Extended Operation failure: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.archive.operations.WebComponentExportOperation
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard.performFinish(DataModelWizard.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:752)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3880)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$Export.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.run(CommandAction.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.ExportResourcesAction.run(ExportResourcesAction.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BaseSelectionListenerAction.runWithEvent(BaseSelectionListenerAction.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3880)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: Error exportingWar File
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.J2EEArtifactExportOperation.execute(J2EEArtifactExportOperation.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard$1$CatchThrowableRunnableWithProgress.run(DataModelWizard.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.SaveFailureException: Error opening archive for export..
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.archive.operations.WebComponentExportOperation.export(WebComponentExportOperation.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.J2EEArtifactExportOperation.execute(J2EEArtifactExportOperation.java:123)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.ArchiveSaveFailureException: Error saving archive: WebComponentArchiveLoadAdapter, Component: P/Nautilus2 to output path: D:/Nautilus2.war
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.internal.ArchiveFactoryImpl.saveArchive(ArchiveFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.J2EEArtifactExportOperation.saveArchive(J2EEArtifactExportOperation.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.archive.operations.WebComponentExportOperation.export(WebComponentExportOperation.java:50)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\myproject.war (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.internal.ArchiveFactoryImpl.createSaveAdapterForJar(ArchiveFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.internal.ArchiveFactoryImpl.saveArchive(ArchiveFactoryImpl.java:74)
    ... 13 more
Contains: Extended Operation failure: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.archive.operations.WebComponentExportOperation
org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: Error exportingWar File
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.J2EEArtifactExportOperation.execute(J2EEArtifactExportOperation.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1800)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard$1$CatchThrowableRunnableWithProgress.run(DataModelWizard.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.SaveFailureException: Error opening archive for export..
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.archive.operations.WebComponentExportOperation.export(WebComponentExportOperation.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.J2EEArtifactExportOperation.execute(J2EEArtifactExportOperation.java:123)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.ArchiveSaveFailureException: Error saving archive: WebComponentArchiveLoadAdapter, Component: P/Nautilus2 to output path: D:/Nautilus2.war
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.internal.ArchiveFactoryImpl.saveArchive(ArchiveFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.J2EEArtifactExportOperation.saveArchive(J2EEArtifactExportOperation.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.archive.operations.WebComponentExportOperation.export(WebComponentExportOperation.java:50)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\myproject.war (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.internal.ArchiveFactoryImpl.createSaveAdapterForJar(ArchiveFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.internal.ArchiveFactoryImpl.saveArchive(ArchiveFactoryImpl.java:74)
    ... 13 more
```

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 2):

That may be related to [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg12329.html)

> It looks like you have another version of java sdk installed on your machine (probably 1.4) and eclipse is launching with that instead of your 5.0 vm. You can try using a -vm parameter in the `eclipse.ini` file to specify the vm to run with.

(See this **[eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)** to make sure of your JVM used to launch Eclipse)

---

On second thought, the "Caused by" errrors are quite clear:

```
org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.ArchiveSaveFailureException:  
Error saving archive: WebComponentArchiveLoadAdapter,  
Component: P/Nautilus2 to output path: D:/Nautilus2.war
```

and:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\myproject.war (Access is denied)
```

So do you have any ACL restrictions on `D:\`?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 5 years old, but people keep coming to this page for similar errors even today.

**My solution (workaround) may help others:**

1. Build project (the one you are exporting)
2. Close project.
3. Re-open the
   project.
4. Try exporting again.

This should work with EAR or WAR exporting options.